# Xamarin Cross-Platform App Solution Build failed?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am absolutely new to Xamarin form. I think my question that i am going to ask will be not too good but the problem i faced is very strange and i don't know how to solved it.

**Problem:**
I created a brand new Cross-Platform project in visual studio 2017.
and a wrote some code and when i run my application the Build Solution is failed.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label x:Name="_label"  Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Entry x:Name="EnterYourName" Placeholder="Write your name"/>
        <Button Text="Say Hello !" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Form;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _label.Text = "Welcome" + " " + EnterYourName.Text; 
        }
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

> All The necessary using statements are included and when i click
>   on build solution it give me this error...

- The Type or namespace name 'System' could not found (are you missing
  a using  directives or assemblies reference.)
- The Type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not found (are you missing
  a using  directives or assemblies reference.)
- Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported. and so on.

How to solve this issue ? I shall be very thankful.

**Thanks.**

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: if your build fails there should be some explanatory error message that tells you why.  Also, `Text:"Say Hello !"` is invalid, did you mean `Text="Say Hello !"`

Comment: The type of namespace 'System' is not referenced and so on.... @Joe Seweli

Comment: `Cicked="Button_Clicked"`,except for the Clicked property, which is misspelled, the rest of the code looks normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project is fine, so the problem is not code related (unless you have something strange in App.Xaml and App.Xaml.cs).

You may need to:

- clean the project
- restore Nuget packages

If the problem appears only on the single platform you might need to check your connection with Mac or see if you have installed all required Android SDK/components.